# What is the Realm Server URL for a remotely hosted Realm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, realm

I remotely hosted the Realm Server on AWS and I got it to run and I am able to connect to the Realm Dashboard, but I'm not sure how to connect to the Realm Object Server using the Realm Browser App.

I was able to find the admin access token but since the server is remotely hosted what would the Server URL be? The Realm website tutorial provided us with realm://127.0.0.1:9080, but that's only for when the Realm Server is locally hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the localhost IP (in our examples, that is listed as `127.0.0.1`) with the hostname or IP address of your EC2 machine. Please note that the numbers/addresses below are made up. They are just to serve as an example.

Typically, this will be something of the form `198.51.100.38`, giving you the root URL: `realm://192.51.100.38:9080`. To this, you obviously have to append the path of the Realm file that you are trying to access.

Alternatively, you should be able to use the EC2 hostname, if you prefer that. Your EC2 hostname should look something like `ec2-198-51-100-38.compute-1.amazonaws.com`. You should check your EC2 dashboard for more information to get these proper values.

More information:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html